# XMLhttpresponse returning empty array

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have this simple js code:

```
ajax.open("POST", "test.php", true); //
//ajax.setRequestHeader(contentType, mimeType); // SETUP HEADER
//ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
    if(this.status == 200){
      console.log(ajax.response);
    }
  }
}
ajax.send("test");
```

The string "test" should be sent to the test.php file.

The test.php file contains the following:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And the `console.log(ajax.response)` returns an empty array.

Why is it so? Do I have to do something else to get the $_POST print from the php file ?

Comment: if you see a string that looks like an empty array (as opposed to blankness), then it's PHP's fault. edit:  try `ajax.send("hello=world")` ,  also, you should probably use `echo json_encode($var);` instead of `print_r` if you want to consume the data in JS.

Comment: Well you are not sending up a value to the server. And shouldn't you be using `echo`?

Comment: @epascarello Why's that ? I did write ajax.send("test"); And echo($_POST) is invalid because that would be an array to string conversion